# Moving less than 20 resource items to a new resource group took an unusually long time and failed eventually (more than 3hrs)

Tags: azure

was trying to move a few resources into my new resource group then i encountered this in azure shell

[the resource group is being updated xxxx and cannot perform this operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ns7D.png)

then later on after more than 3hrs saw this msg in the activity log

[moving resources failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8whT.png)

really frustrating to wait and to just watch the operation fail after several hours of waiting. wasn't even moving petabyes worth of resources.

**can Azure folks help to improve this feature? or is this the way it is now for Azure?**

would like to mention that the @AzureSupport twitter acct was vry helpful and requested me to post it here so here i am

Comment: latest update:  
     i performed a delete on all items under the new resource group and it was successful. also did the same to the old resource group (source) and also successful. finally i can continue working. but i wish moving fwd that Azure finds a way to either cancel the move operation or make it spit failed error msgs much much earlier i.e. not after more than 3hrs.

Comment: What type of resources were you trying to move? Are the source and destination resource group in the same region?

Comment: type of resources: 3 VMs each less than 50GB in size and related resources like IP, NSG etc
and yes source and destination grp was the same